# Error installing node-weak on Windows7

Tags: node.js

I can't seem to load node-weak on Windows7. I've tried Python 2.7, 2.5, 2.3, to no avail. It seems (from the error below), that I need to use a version of Python2, but changing versions doesn't seem to help. Any help is appreciated.

```
C:\project1\node_modules\weak>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\
bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! rebuild error Error: Python executable "c:\Python25\python.exe" is Pyth
on 3, which is not supported.

gyp ERR! rebuild error     at failPython3 (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_mo
dules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:90:14)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:79:9
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:534:7)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at maybeClose (child_process.js:634:16)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:676:5)
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weak@0.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the weak@0.2.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the weak package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls weak
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "weak"
npm ERR! cwd C:\project1
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.33
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message weak@0.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\project1\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently node-gyp@0.5.2 had a bug where it wouldn't parse the Python version number properly, but that was fixed in 036a730f4a3a95e65d8f390f7f5c4f0d3321e422 (0.5.3).  To fix the issue, I had to update node-gyp:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs"
npm install node-gyp
```

Simple solution, but a difficult problem to track down.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Virtual box on Linux Mint in Windows 7 host. The nodejs(v0.6.19) and npm(v1.1.14) libs I procured through apt-get were outdated. I installed both npm(v1.3.11) and nodejs(v0.10.20) through source code from [here](http://nodejs.org/download/).

I encountered errors when compiling the code in shared folder as symbolic links creation is disabled in shared folders. So, I extracted zips, compiled and installed these files outside the shared folders. This resolved the issue straightaway.